# Problema con CLS en Google Search

Tags: seo, rendimiento, google-search

estoy teniendo un problema con la validación de Google Search que no se como solucionar. Como veis, según la validación tengo problemas con el CLS de mis páginas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, haciendo todo las indicaciones que veo en internet, tanto en PagesPeed como en GtMetrix, todas mis páginas están a mucho menos de 0.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente, no se que más hacer para que me valide correctamente.

Comment: ¿Has probado realizando una auditoría de Lighthouse con el inspeccionador de elementos en alguna de las páginas que te marca Google Search?

Comment: Si, ese es el problema. Que en lighthouse me lo marca a 0.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir algunas de las URLs que Search Console te marca como afectadas?

Comment: https://www.transeop.com/bolsa-de-cargas/

Answer (score 0):

La web que comentas, en efecto, no parece tener problemas de CLS https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-transeop-com-bolsa-de-cargas/sub8vt5d4b?form_factor=mobile

Search Console funciona con grupos de webs, no con paginas individuales. Seria conveniente que miraras/compartieras que webs mas estan afectadas porque, a lo mejor, si tienes otro grupo de paginas con problemas de CLS

Aun asi viendo la fecha de la pregunta supongo que ya lo habras corregido